# How do you transfer an NFT using SolanaWeb3 in the browser?

Tags: web3.js

Can anyone give an example of transferring a Metaplex NFT in the Browser from a wallet you are signed into via browser extension to a wallet address?

Answer (score 1):

NFT is a Token from SPL Program with decimals 0 and supply 1. So transferring an NFT is same is transferring a token. Look at this code snippet to understand more on transferring SPL token [here](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-transfer-tokens)

Comment: How do you get "spl-token" into the Browser since you cannot "require" it? I need to send the NFT in the browser similar to how NFT exchanges send it in the browser, not on the backend. Also can you give a code example?

Comment: The above solanacookbook link is the code example and you have to use @solana/spl-token package to interact with browser. I am not sure what spl-token in your question refers to

Comment: I'm not using React framework though, so I can't include "spl-token" like that how they mention. How can I include it in a <script> tag? Many people are not using React framework and may be using a different Server-Side technology like Python/Java/PHP/Ruby

Comment: I am not sure regarding another language's but if you want to work in a JS/TS environment than spl-token has to be used